# Smallest number of steps to sort a list to smaller and bigger halves

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Given a list from 1 to n (in random order), what is the smallest number of steps that it takes to sort the list so that the smaller numbers are on the left and the bigger ones on the right? With each step, two adjacent numbers can be switched. My function:

```
def solve(t):
    count = 0
    n = len(t)//2
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if t[-i] <= n:
            count += 1
    if t[0] == 1:
        n -= 1
    return count*n
```

solve([2, 1, 4, 3])  returns 0, because the list is already in wanted order.

solve([5, 3, 4, 1, 6, 2]) returns 6, because it takes 6 steps to sort to bigger and smaller halves: [5,3,4,1,6,2]→[5,3,4,1,2,6]→[3,5,4,1,2,6]→[3,5,1,4,2,6]→[3,1,5,4,2,6]→[3,1,5,2,4,6]→[3,1,2,5,4,6]

It seems to work however, solve([5, 2, 6, 4, 1, 3]) returns 6 even though it takes 7 steps to get the desired order.

How can I fix the function?

EDIT: n is always even and the number of numbers on each side should be equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the numbers are 1 to n you immediately know in which half a number belongs. You could replace all numbers smaller (or equal) than n/2 with false and the rest with true, how many steps does it take to get all false values to the beginning only using adjacent swaps? Same answer, but easier problem to think about it, at least for me. So all we have to do is to count the number of all false values to the right of each true value.

```js
function solve(arr) {
  const nhalf = Math.floor(arr.length / 2)
  let total = 0, count = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > nhalf)
      count++ // same as: count = count + 1
    else
      total += count // same as: total = total + count
  }
  return total
}

console.log(solve([5,3,4,1,6,2]))
```

The scientific term of what we are doing is: *counting the number of inversions* (thanks @Kelly Bundy).

Comment: "So all we have to do is to count the number of false values to the right of each true value": I don't thinks so, the number of swaps also depends on the absolute positions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It depends how you are counting. The way I count it doesn't matter and should give the same result. Let's assume I have two true values to the left of a false value, it doesn't matter where they are, you only have to swap this false value with those two true values once, so 2 swaps independent of position (all other false values in between are counted separately).

Comment: Sorry, I thought false value *immediately* to the right.

Comment: *"the number of false values to the right of each true value"* - A.k.a. the number of inversions. I don't think you need floor, and could use `for (a of arr)`. And I'd also fix their wrong name, e.g., call it `h` (or `half`) instead of `n` (since that's already defined by "Given a list from 1 to n").

Comment: @maraca thank you. How would the for-loop look in Python

Comment: @KellyBundy 1. edited answer, 2. When dealing with integers in JS floor is an auto-reflex, it doesn't hurt (wouldn't do it for any other language with proper integer division). I use this `for` on purpose, it should be available in almost any programming language and easily understandable. The only reason I use JS is so you can see the result immediately and play around with it.

Comment: @ita algorithmic questions shouldn't be language-specific. I can help you with any part you don't understand in the JS program, but I'm not translating it to Python, this is your task.

Comment: The `for` loop in Python would start `for i in range(len(arr)):`.

Comment: @btilly Using bad Javascript to teach bad Python... Ugh :-)